# How to setup laravel passport to work on different database for unit tests

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to setup/configure laravel passport for testing database.

So, I have two database connections (`mysql` and `mysql_testing`)

`mysql` database connection is for development/production data.

`mysql_testing` database connection is for unit tests.

My problem is how to install passport client for `mysql_testing` ?

If I run `php artisan passport:install` command, then the Laravel will create clients only in `mysql` database connection, and everything works fine/properly without any error or trouble.

But, in `mysql_testing` database connection the client is not created and I got an error

`Personal access client not found. Please create one.`

So, how is it possible to install/setup/add the clients in `mysql_testing` database connection ?
Or there is some other way/approach for testing ?

Laravel version is 6.0
Error is on this line (Test create user):

```php
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $user->createToken('ApiToken');
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to test the authentication itself, just use `$this->actingAs($user)` on your tests. Let this responsibility to the laravel/passport package maintainers.

Comment: @EliasSoares I'm using laravel passport for REST API token based auth, also I have few other important operations on `register` and `login` (also I have some data in the response that is necessary for the UI), and my idea was to cover those scenarios with unit tests. Maybe will be better if I find other solution...